# Firefox Addon Load Different Scripts on Different URLs with PageMod

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am building an addon for Firefox that will load a JS file depending on what URL you are on.

I have used PageMod and have successfully loaded a script on a specified page, however when I introduce a second page detection and a second script it does not detect it- the first one still works though.

This is the original code with only one page that worked:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "https://www.examplesite1.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: ["./jquery.js","./script1.js","./ga.js"]     
});
```

I assumed that seeing as it was structured like a JSON array I could just add another item like so:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "https://www.examplesite1.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: ["./jquery.js","./script1.js","./ga.js"]     
},
{
  include: "https://www.examplesite2.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: ["./jquery.js","./script2.js","./ga.js"]     
});
```

This second version still works for the first URL but not for the second. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed in the end. The way to do it is to declare a new Pagemod for each URL to detect.

So instead of this:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "https://www.examplesite1.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: ["./jquery.js","./script1.js","./ga.js"]     
},
{
  include: "https://www.examplesite2.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: ["./jquery.js","./script2.js","./ga.js"]     
});
```

I did this:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "https://www.examplesite1.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: ["./jquery.js","./script1.js","./ga.js"]     
}
);

var pageMod2 = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod2.PageMod({
  include: "https://www.examplesite2.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: ["./jquery.js","./script2.js","./ga.js"]     
});
```

It now works for both sites.